# Undiscontinued entity status enter in filed patent what does it mean?

Tags: status, entity

what does entity stauts undiscontinued mean? The is listed in the patent filed.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean "undiscounted".

This means that there are no fee discounts for being a small or micro entity.